# How to avoid navigate back when the user types backspace on a HTML text input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

Backspace is the browser hotkey for Navigate Back To The Last Page. I know that when an input has the focus this hotkey is disabled. But I have keyup and keydown events binded to this input, and something I wrote is causing this trouble.

Do you know the solution?

Comment: Is your issue that the input has focus and the Backspace IS navigating back, or you want it to and its not? What exactly is the behaviour that you're seeing?

Comment: If you suspect that something you wrote is causing the issue probably best to post the code here. Otherwise almost impossible to determine a solution.

Comment: Exactly. It must not navigate back. In the present it is unfortunately doing it.

Comment: could you describe what this "something I wrote" does?

Comment: the code is here: http://code.google.com/p/task-management/source/browse/trunk/scripts/index.js

Comment: in which browser does backspace navigate back. i've never seen that before

Comment: @Simon any windows browser does that: ie, ff and chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by the input removal before returning the onKeyDown event.

Answer (score 1):

when you have handled the event from the input element, cancel that event's bubbling before returning.

Comment: both event.preventDefault() or event.stopPropagation() solves the problem on IE and Chrome. But I still haven't found the solution for Firefox http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar need i.e. to neutralize the Back action caused by Backspace key and I came across a solution on this site

http://www.webmasterworld.com/javascript/3785986.htm

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

try this on your onKeyDown or onKeyPress even

```
if (event.keyCode==8)//where 8 ascii code of backspace
{
retunr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to hook into window.onbeforeunload event to prevent such accidental navigation.

Answer (score 0):

That you can make:

1. You can set a listener for InputField and look all keydown events.
2. In event listener you can make a buffer variable, which have a real InputField value.

So, if you accept a not Backspace code then new value of buffer will be InputField value and you make use your hotKeyFunction, else new value of InputField will be buffer value and you get a normal working of InputField.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (typeof(window.event)!='undefined')//ie
   {document.onkeydown=function()
                       {var tag_name=event.srcElement.tagName.toUpperCase();
                        if (tag_name!='INPUT' && tag_name!='TEXTAREA')
                           {return event.keyCode!=8;
                           }
                       };
   }
else //firefox, chrome
    {window.addEventListener('keydown',function(evt){if (evt.keyCode==8){evt.preventDefault();}}, true);
    }
```