# How to prevent backspace from navigating back after .remove()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a HTML table with An input inside a cell. If the user has focus in an input without any content and hits backspace, I want to remove all the row of the input. The problem is that after i remove the row, the page is navigating back (the behavior expected if the focus was not in a input). I`m  new to JQuery and do not know if it`s a matter of stoping the propagation of the event  after the input was removed. How can I prevent this behavior (the navigation back)?

Obs: I`m using Jquery in an asp .NET MVC4 WebApp.

Code:

```
$(function () {
            $("td").click(function ()
            {
                if (!$(this).hasClass("cellEditing"))
                {        
                    $(this).children().first().keydown(function (e) 
                    {
                        switch (e.which)
                        {

                            case 8:
                                var newContent = $(this).val();
                                if (newContent == "")
                                {
                                    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
                                }
                                break;
                         }
                    }
                 }
             }
}
```

Comment: There is a simmilar problem in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156953/how-to-avoid-navigate-back-when-the-user-types-backspace-on-a-html-text-input?rq=1 .It is said that the problem is the remotion of the input as I suspected, but no suggestion of solution is provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use e.preventDefault() in the keydown event handler.

Comment: Tried that, but the backspace stops working all together. If i put this line of code right below the .remove() and insert a breakpoint there it wont be hitting. It won`t even delete the letter in a normal behavior. Am I missing something?

Comment: Try putting it into the keyup or keypress event then. I'm actually not sure if back is triggered on keydown, on keypress or on keyup. Or manually delete the letter from the selected input

Comment: The suggested did not work directly but I made it work by changing the event to keypress and returning  false right after the .remove(). Thank you for the help Buch.